# Issues connecting button to webView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uibutton

I have a UIWebView that is supposed to open when the button is pressed, but nothing is happening on the simulator when it is pressed. Can someone maybe see something I did wrong? I can't figure out what it is. Here is the IBAction for the button:

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http:coronetjck.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with those lines, it must be something else in your code elsewhere.

Comment: Is webView an IBOutlet?  Did you connect it to your web view in IB?

Comment: The webview is null. I connected the button to the WebView in IB, and it is also an outlet. There must be something else wrong in my code. Does anyone know any good articles or tutorials that could help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you missing 2 backslashes from the URL?

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http:coronetjck.com";
```

should be:

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://coronetjck.com";
```

Comment: That's not it, Webkit auto corrects it and can load that url.